# Macro to combine sheets and get value only (not formulas)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to merge sheets into one, and only get the values of cells.

[The code I have](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1184-excel-merge-multiple-worksheets-into-one.html) only does part of the job (it gets formulas instead of values).

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

Additionally, I'd like to ignore the first two rows.

Any clues?

Comment: `Any clues?` Sure :) But I would like to know your understanding of the code first. What do you think is getting you the formula? How do you think a cell's formula can be converted to values? :)

Comment: [Offtopic] I am actually horrified looking at the code... and to think that it came from `http://www.extendoffice.com/`

Comment: Hey @SiddharthRout, I'm not actually a VBA wiz, so I wouldn't be able to answer you that. And that's actually the reason why I'm sharing this with you and your brilliant minds ;)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how stackoverflow works :) No Offense but you just can't dump a code from some other site here and ask people to do stuff for you. You need to show minimal understanding of the code.

Comment: None taken ;) I'm sorry if I don't meet your criteria for helping other people out. I've done this (helping without requiring previous knowledge) a number of times with work colleagues who needed help with jQuery, for example, and they had no idea what that was for. When you do that, you hope to get that same kind of help from other people, but that's not always the case. I hope someone else here feels the same way as I do. No offense ;)

Comment: There's helping people out and there's helping people on SO. If you choose to take advantage of SO, implicit when you post a question here, you should follow the community's guidelines for soliciting help. Furthermore, @SiddharthRout **is** trying to help you. He always tries to teach someone to fish, not just hand them fish. Which is in fact the spirit of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally agree with Siddharth, the code doesn't look god. But to fix your issue, just use paste special values. Replace

the line `Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")` with `Selection.Copy: Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

and line `Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)` with `Selection.Copy: Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

The colon (:) here is just a line breaker